# TeraData aggregate function

Tags: sql, aggregate, teradata

When I try to select couple of columns with count, I get the following error:

> Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group

My query is something like this.

```
SELECT COUNT(1), COLUMN1, COLUMN2 
FROM TABLE-NAME
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're after a count for each combination of COLUMN1 and COLUMN2:

```
SELECT COUNT(1), COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY COLUMN1, COLUMN2
```

If you're after a count of all records in the table:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) OVER (), COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM TABLE_NAME
```